# SSIS is doubling up backslashes

Tags: variables, ssis, enumeration, backslash, foreach-loop-container

I am loading some file names and locations as variables into SSIS, then tried using foreach loop to execute a process task.

after a few unsuccessful attempts I realized SSIS is doubling up all the Backslashes in the fields I am loading into my variables. hence the network addresses not working.

can we stop this behavior?

What I load:

```
"\\BBBB001\shared\GGGG\PiMSSSRSReportsPath\THM022\HHHH-NextWorkingDay-at1530.pdf"
```

What I get:

```
"\\\\BBBB001\\shared\\GGGG\\PiMSSSRSReportsPath\\THM022\\HHHH-NextWorkingDay-at1530.pdf"
```

SSIS Execute Process task:
[image]

as you can see foxit reader doesn't recognize the later filename with double backslashes. if I manually inter the first value it will work.

Comment: where did you use the 2nd path in your package? 2nd one is a legit path, `\` is the escape sign

Comment: I don't think this is the error, since the added backslash is an escape character `"\\"` is evaluated as `"\"`

Comment: @Hadi it causes issue as this link is passed as an argument to Foxit reader to be printed ultimately.

Comment: @LONG I used it in a execute process task..Foxit reader gives me error as file not found...using breakpoints I realized SSIS is doubling backslashes and that's why foxit reader can't find the file.

Comment: Where are you loading these from and how are you loading them? That seems like pretty important information to provide

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I am loading them through a execute sql task from a SQL Server table. file names and printer names..simple stuff. again if I put the value manually in execute process task it works.

Comment: I know it's simple stuff but it would appear that this is the part that is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I found a workaround:

Instead of adding variables in Arguments section, I created a single variable including all the parameters for the file to be printed. something like this:

```
 /t "FileLocation\FileName.pdf" PrinterName
```

And then put this variable in the expression section of the Execute process task, add argument and put that final variable in front it. like this:

[image]